# WPF/XAML compiles but errors show in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources

With a colleague, we try to make a POC of a WPF application. We created a new project with a page and a resx file to test internationalization (we are French). The application work well, no error on the compile and the resx file give good data.
but in the XAML file, we have a lot of errors.

Here is the XAML header:

```
<Window x:Class="MAPPrintProcessEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:res="clr-namespace:MAPPrintProcessEditor.Properties"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MAP Print Process Editor"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        Height="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight}" Width="{Binding SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth}">
```

Here, is a line marked in error:

```
<MenuItem Header="{x:Static res:Resources.MenuItemHeaderClose}">
    <MenuItem.Icon>
        <Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/Close-16.png"/>
    </MenuItem.Icon>
</MenuItem>
```

Visual Studio underline only this part:

```
Header="{x:Static
```

And finally, here is the error message:

> The name "Resources" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:PrintProcessEditor.Properties"

What is wrong in this code?

We use VS2017 and .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: If the solution builds OK but you get fake errors in the XAML designer, clean the solution, close and reopen it, and do a clean build. The XAML designer is a little funny sometimes.

Comment: I have already tried that ;)

Comment: In that case, as long as you can still build, just ignore it.

Comment: ok, but we can't see what we do in our XAML until we compile in this case :/

Comment: What versions of .net / visual studio?

Comment: We us VS2017 and .Net 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

If the you can build correctly than just ignore that message and use BLEND to design your app.

Comment: the issue is the same with Blend ;)